# How do I move the google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am making an application for Android using the Google Maps API. I load a map to locate my position, but I have a problem. When I move to another location, I immediately returned my position centered on the screen. I would rather that the map would remain at the point where I have moved.

Here is my code:

```
private void setCurrentLocation(Location location)
{               
    if(location != null)
    {
        // Aggiorna la location
        Lat = location.getLatitude();
        Long = location.getLongitude();

        int latitudeE6 = (int) Math.floor(Lat * 1.0E6);
        int longitudeE6 = (int) Math.floor(Long * 1.0E6);

        GeoPoint p1 = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
        GeoPoint p2 = new GeoPoint(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        // Aggiorna la posizione corrente
        currentLatitude = latitudeE6;
        currentLongitude = longitudeE6;

        // Sposta la posizione corrente sulla mappa di F_Map
        F_Map.mapController.setCenter(p1);

        // Calcola i metri appena fatti
        float dist = Distance.getDistance(p1, p2) *1000;

        if(dist > 1) // maggiore di 1 metro
        {                               
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "distance: "+dist,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             try 
             {
                 SendMyPositionToDB(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
             } catch(IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }                               
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you set:

```
F_Map.mapController.setCenter(p2);
```

Instead of p1?

Comment: The problem is not the coordinates.
Now the map is moved each time the GPS detects a shift (map.setCenter (); in onChangeLocation ()).
I want to make sure that when you touch the screen, the setCenter is disabled and then re-activated when you press a special button.